# Qml context object is null on app shutdown

Tags: c++, qt, qml

This is my code.
I get those errors in the console every time I quit the application.
Properties work just fine during execution, but I get this annoying warning every time.

> qrc:/search.qml:17: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConnected' of null
> qrc:/search.qml:18: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scanStatus' of null
> qrc:/search.qml:19: TypeError: Cannot read property 'device' of null

```
#main.cpp

Utility u;
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("utility", &u);
```

```
#search.qml

property bool connected : utility.isConnected
property bool scanRunning : utility.scanStatus
property var searchedDevice : utility.device
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to verify that `utility` is not null:

```
property bool connected : utility ? utility.isConnected : false
property bool scanRunning : utility ? utility.scanStatus : false
property var searchedDevice : utility ? utility.device : null
```

Comment: Or even better using nullish coalescing and optional chaining operators
`property bool connected: utility?.isConnected ?? false` and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your `Utility` object is not destroyed after your QML engine: create it before the engine if both are created on the stack.
No need to check if `utility` is null with this solution.